# How to disconnect to old file when react compile

Tags: reactjs

I need react to refer to file 'DishdetailComponent.js' when compile but somehow react connects to old file, even though I already renamed old file to different name. Below is compiling error when I moved the renamed old file out of the folder to try to fully cut off the connection.

How can I fix so react will refer to current file 'DishdetailComponent.js' during build time? Thanks

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Wk2_bef_function_DishdetailComponent.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Full stack web. HK university\React\confusion\src\components\Wk2_bef_function_DishdetailComponent.js'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Comment: is this your old file name : Wk2_bef_function_DishdetailComponent.js ?

Comment: Yes, that is the old file. When I saved old file as a back up with another name, there is pop up asking if I want to proceed with file imports and I accept which I think I should not. I suspect this step made the connection to old file.

Comment: you need to refer to your new file, it is still looking for old file.
./src/components/<new file name>.
it would be better if you can post code of the file where you  are making this import.

Comment: Vote up :)! I think the same and just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

@ Prakash, via answering you I think of how to fix it. I think the auto file imports may be the cause. I then go back and search through all import commands. Bingo it shows react auto import for the renamed old file. I remove it and route import command to the right file.

Comment: Great. Happy coding